# Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10d54a4c0) to 'UIButton' (0x10d552120)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uibutton

there was a question like this already made but I tried the suggestions and it didn't work for me still. :/

I am trying to make a quiz app using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNAQ3Y8PGkM&t=1s

Here is a link to download my project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwvg6fyrrzudued/kat%20quiz.zip?dl=0

Everything is perfect except I get the error:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10d54a4c0) to 'UIButton' (0x10d552120)

I'd really appreciate some help. I tried everything in my knowledge and searching, thank you. :)

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     let questions = ["What color is Courage the Cowardly Dog?", "What is the name of the woman that lives with Courage?", "What is the name of the man that lives with Courage?"]
     let answers = [["Purple","Grey","Orange"],["Muriel", "Angela", "Elizabeth"], ["Eustace", "Robert", "Ezio"]]

    //Variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
    var points = 0

    //Label
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

    //Button
    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print ("RIGHT!")
            points += 1
        }
        else
        {
            print ("WRONG!!!!!!")
        }
        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
        else{
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScore", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        newQuestion()
    }



    //Function that displays new question
    func newQuestion(){
        lbl.text = questions[currentQuestion]
        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(3)+1

        //Create a button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...3
        {
            //Create a button
            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

            if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
            }

            else
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                x = 2
            }

        }
        currentQuestion += 1
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify? I'm super new to programming. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create UI Button in your Story Board ??
In your youtube video, watch 1:45

And remember to set your 3 UI Button's tag to 1, 2 and 3
watch 3:20

Your problem occurs because you've set your View's tag = 1.

You can fix it easily by change View's tag value to a number != 1, 2 and 3

[image]

Because your ViewController have 2 view with the same tag = 1. (`view` and `UI Button`). 
So when you use `view.viewWithTag(i)`, It accidentally select `view` not `UI Button`. So it can not convert to `UI Button` type

P/s: next time, if you want to select your Button directly, you can make an `@IBOutlet` for that `Button` as you make with your `Label`. It will not cause confusing error like that

Comment: Yes I did both of this. I just redid it again but still have same problem :/

Comment: At 1:45, Did you choose **UI Button** or You accidentally choose **UI View**?

Comment: I chose UI button

Comment: I added a dropbox link to my project file

Comment: Your problem in your StoryBoard. Because your view's tag = 1. Duplicate with Button's tag... I've edited my answer... see Above!

Comment: If you can fix your error.... Can you set my answer to Accepted! Tks a lot

Comment: it works !!!! yay thank you! I cant find where to set your answer as accepted. I have limited priviledges as a new member :/

Comment: Just click at the 'gray stick simple' on the top left of my answer (below the vote up and down)... Thanks a lot!